# Accessing custom product attributes on custom form page (not product / category view page)

Tags: product-attribute, forms, custom-attributes

Is there any way of accessing the current / most recently viewed product on a custom contact form-type page?

For example, a user is on a product view page, then clicks a link which takes them to a page with a form. I'd like to pre-populate one field of the form with an attribute from the current product (the product page that led to this custom form page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snevart,whem you click on the link from product page that times you need to send product in url.Thus using this product id you can product details using load  product  object `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` then you can easy get product attribute on this page.